# Hyperconjugation in o-Cresolate and p-Cresolate anions

Tags: stability, phenols, hyperconjugation, inductive-effect

I have read that hyperconjugation as an effect works only with an empty orbital available to share sigma-electrons with. Based on that, the 'destabilizing' effect of hyperconjugation on alkoxides is not taken into account when judging their relative basic strengths.

$\ce{MeO- > EtO- > iPrO- > tBuO-}$

based on only inductive effects.

In judging the stability of cresolates, the 'destabilizing' effect of hyperconjugation is taken into account for the ortho and para positions.

My question is why is hyperconjugation being taken into account even when there is no vacant orbital to overlap the electrons with in the first place?